# Copy directory recursively in pure C on Linux/UNIX

Tags: c, linux, unix, copy

Can someone guide me on a possible solution? I don't want to use `/bin/cp` or any other foreign apps. I want my program to be independent. Also I know that every system is quite specific, so I'm interested in UNIX/Linux compatibility.

How can I solve it? Just going down the source directory and creating a new directories in the target one and copying files in them, or there is a better solution?

BTW my goal is: *copy all first level subdirs recursively into target dir if they are not present there*

Comment: Is this homework? You last sentence sounds suspicious. If it is, please tag it as such.

Comment: Why re-invent the wheel ? Why not just use e.g. `rsync` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really need some kind of recursive descent into the directory tree. Doing this, you can actually make this very portable (using `opendir`/`readdir` on Linux and `FindFirstFile`/`FindNextFile` on Windows). The problem that remains is the actual copying. You can use the C standard library for that with the following algorithm:

- Open source file
- Open target file
- In a loop, `fread` a block of constant size from the source, then `fwrite` it to the target. Stop if the source file contains no more data

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the POSIX [`nftw(3)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/nftw.html) function to walk the tree you want to copy. You supply this function with a callback function that gets called on the path of each file/directory. Define a callback that copies the file/dir it gets called on into the destination tree. The fourth callback argument of type `struct FTW *` can be used to compute the relative path.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think you can restrict the depth of this walk.

Comment: @NiklasB.: there was no such requirement in your question. No, you can't restrict the depth of the walk, but you do get the depth in the callback.

Comment: It's not my question, but it contains this "first level subdirs" constraint. Thanks for the additional info.

Comment: @NiklasB.: ah, that's what you mean. You can do that by checking in the callback if you are at least at level 2; if you're not, then don't copy non-directories. Alternatively, just write a regular copy-tree algorithm using `nftw` and call it on each subdir in a loop, skipping the files.

Comment: yes, this should be quite useful, os when I'll target a directory that should be copied, I can use `nftw` to copy all the tree.

Comment: One more question. My callback function should somehow know the destination dir (where to copy passed file/dir). Can I do this somehow without putting it in the global variable?

Comment: @Uko: unfortunately, you can't pass extra arguments to the callback, so you'll need to make the destination path a global or `static` variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use only C, you could use dirent.h. Using this, you can recursively follow the directory structure. Then you could open the files in the binary mode, and write them to the desired location via write stream.