# Is it possible to include a shell script in a C program

Tags: c

I've been successful in writing a C program that copies files from one directory to another and I'm trying to write one that copies directories and sub-directories to another directory.

I've equally been able to write a shell script that copies directories and sub-directories from one location to another.

So, I wish to ask if it is possible to include a shell script into a C program so I won't have to spend time writing another C program to copy directories and sub-directories.

Comment: It is possible, but it generally doesn't make sense.

Comment: Try this: `system("/path/filename.sh");`

Answer (score 2):

Yes its definately possible to call shell scripts or other scripts/executables from C using `system(..)` function call. Check [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html).

For the given task of copying directories and subdirectories you can easily code it in C using `opendir()`, `readdir()`, and other API's.

Check [Copy directory recursively in pure C on Linux/UNIX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9192295/copy-directory-recursively-in-pure-c-on-linux-unix) for more details